# How much smoke to expect from making a roux?

Tags: oil, roux

I live in an apartment and am considering making a roux for a gumbo. I've seen methods for using [an oven to make the roux](https://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/shrimp-gumbo-recipe-1946875), but I've noticed that there's a high possibility of [getting a lot of smoke with a roux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrCHZ86kOH4).

Even if I use a relatively high smoke-point oil (e.g. peanut or avocado), how much smoke can I expect from making a roux? Is making a roux / gumbo only advisable for a very well-ventilated kitchen?

I don't want to have a continuous battle with my smoke alarm as I go through the process of making the roux. I live in a relatively cold area, and although keeping windows open is an option, I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: I've never found it necessary to cook a roux at a temperature high enough to smoke.

Comment: There is a huge difference between browning (toasting) the flour for a roux and burning it. If it is smoking then you're burning it and it will taste horrible.

Comment: Do you have an overhead fan for your oven? That would help alleviate concern, however as mentioned above, your roux really should not be brought to smoking point. https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-make-roux-995452 this is a good step-by-step resource.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses! These were all extremely helpful comments!

Comment: There are a few ways to make a surprisingly good roux in the microwave, assuming you have one. These would probably decrease the chance of smoke if your burner is wacky or you get distracted (like I do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a roux is all about cooking the flour to the desired color.  It can take from 3 to 15 minutes.  Do this over medium heat.  Stir constantly.  You should not experience any smoking when making a roux.  If you are experiencing smoke, turn the heat down.

Comment: I think you could remove "excessive". It just shouldn't smoke.

Comment: @Cascabel fair point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a dry roux? 3 cups of AP flour, spread evenly on a rimmed baking sheet and baked at 400°F for an hour to an hour and a half, stirring it about every 15 minutes, until the flour is nutty brown and aromatic. Cool the roux, and add the desired amount to the gumbo, no need to brown it further.